# Rotate latitude (y) tick labels - cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

Is there a way to rotate the latitude tick labels in a cartopy map? I know it is a very easy and usual option in GIS programs such as QGIS, but I couldn't find anything on the subject when using cartopy.

Below there's a simple example (I plot my own shapefiles, that I don't express here):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter

mapp = plt.subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
mapp.set_extent([-44.2, -45.6, -23.36, -24.35])

mapp.set_yticks([-23.5,-24], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
mapp.set_xticks([-44.5,-45.5], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(number_format='.1f')
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter(number_format='.1f')
mapp.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
mapp.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
plt.show()
```

It's not the best MCVE, but anyway, it shows the latitude tick labels horizontally -- that's a standard. My question is: is there a way to rotate the latitude tick labels (or the y tick labels) in 90° so they get vertical?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? For your question that would be something like code that creates an example longitude coordinates in the way you have them, and whatever you mean by a "map frame", with details of what you want to transform those objects to.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon thanks for your income. Very helpful with beginners like me. The example I put is not the best, I adapted from my code, but it may clarify what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a cartopy axes is just a special matplotlib axes, a lot of what you can do to a matplotlib plot, you can also do to a cartopy plot.

For rotating tick labels, there is an [example in the matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html).

So, to rotate your y tick labels you just need to add the following to your code:

```
plt.yticks(rotation='vertical')
```

I also noticed that your map extents are in the wrong order. The order should be

```
[x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max]
```

So your code should look like:

```
mapp.set_extent([-24.35, -23.36, -45.6, -44.2])
```

Comment: Thanks @ldreyer! I hadn't thought that way, cartopy being dependent on matplotlib's parameters. BTW, the set_extent is right, I switched the coordinates in the set_xticks and set_yticks lines. I corrected it in the question. Thanks again!